# Минус в начале строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

- `/[^0-9]/`  - находит нечисловые символы.
- `/[^-0-9]/` - находит нечисловые символы или не минус.

Как составить выражение, чтобы оно находило  нечисловые символы и минус, который не в начале строки?

Comment: Насколько я сумел понять, стоит задача на проверку корректности ввода целого числа?

Вам важно именно найти некорректный символ, или все же достаточно проверки, что строка представляет собой целое число (возможно с минусом)?

Answer (score 1):

Под выражение попадают один и более не числовых символов с начала строки, кроме случая, когда строка начинается со знака минус:

```
/^(?!-)\D*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так. В самом простом варианте:

```
#\D*-\D*#
```

Соответствует минусу, перед которым 0 и больше не цифровых знаков и после которого 0 и больше не цифровых знаков.

Comment: А если не подходит, то вопрос конкретнее задай.